# Jenkins Flexible Publish plugin if else condition

Tags: if-statement, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using the flexible publish plugin for jenkins and found it very useful. My goal is to pass a set of predefined parameters from a job to trigger another downstream job. The downstream job performs an action based on the string match evaluation. But if i dont pass the parameters the job would fail saying

Exception caught evaluating condition: [org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.MacroEvaluationException: Unrecognized macro 'multinodeind' in '${multinodeind}'], action = [Fail the build]

I want to do an if else flow. If the parameter is present evaluate it and proceed. Otherwise perform another action. Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know you can add parameters with default values under ***Meta Data*** → ☑ *This build is parameterized* → ***Add parameter,** do you?* The default values are supposed to be taken if a value for a parameter isn't passed, IIRC.

However, you can use the [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) in the project configuration's **Build** section:

> *A buildstep wrapping any number of other buildsteps, controlling their execution based on a defined condition.*

Comment: Thank you Gerold. I got it working using the default values approach.